# How to get click listener of push notification in IONIC2

Tags: cordova, typescript, push-notification, ionic2

I am working with following plugins for receive GCM push notifications.
 ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push 
 install --save @ionic/cloud-angular

I got success for receive the push notification, but not able to set click listener.

How to set click listener of notification?

Please help me if anybody know regarding push notification handling using IONIC2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, now if anybody got issue like me can get reference from here and save time and efforts.

Create a sample ionic version 2 typescript project $ **ionic start pushapp tutorial --v2 --ts**

Add cordova push plugin $ **cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID="XXXXXXXXX"** 
here XXXXX is your google project number

Open app.ts and import push **import {Push} from 'ionic-native';**

Update the app.ts's initializeApp method with

```
 initializeNotification() {
    let push = Push.init({
        android: {
            senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        },
        ios: {
            alert: "true",
            badge: true,
            sound: 'false'
        },
        windows: {}
    });
    push.on('registration', (data) => {
        console.log(data.registrationId);
        alert(data.registrationId.toString());
    });
    push.on('notification', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        alert("Hi, Am a push notification and message is : " + data.message);
    });
    push.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
}
```

Create android platform $ **ionic platform add android**

Build android $ **ionic build android**

Deploy to android device $ **ionic run android**

-> Now you can test your Push notification using http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/

-> Here you have to submit following details :

**Device token** will be registrationId, which will be printed in log console.

**Message** will be text whatever we want yo send to user

**API key** will be server key generated from google console

Comment: You can use this online tester which supports both Android and iOS. Easy to use simple website pushtry.com supports multiple Tokens and custom JSON

 1. Enter API Key
 2. Enter device token
 3. Enter message
 5. Send